# RxAndroid: Know When Individual Operations Complete as well as When All of them Completes

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am new to RxJava, I have managed to implement RxJava with Retrofit to download multiple files concurrently using flatMap. I am successfully receiving the onComplete Status of individual Downloads. But I am not able to implement Functionality where I receive a Completion Status of **all** the Downloads.

Below is my code I am using for multiple downloads:

```
private void downloadFile(String url, final File parentFolder) {
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url.replace(uri.getLastPathSegment(),""))
            .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()).build();
    RestApi restApi = retrofit.create(RestApi.class);
    restApi.downloadFile(url)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Response<ResponseBody>, Observable<File>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<File> call(final Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                    return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public File call() throws Exception {
                            File file = new File(parentFolder.getAbsoluteFile(), uri.getLastPathSegment());

                            if (!file.exists()) {
                                file.createNewFile();

                                BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file));
                                sink.writeAll(responseBodyResponse.body().source());
                                sink.close();
                            }
                            return file;
                        }
                    });
                }
            },3)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<File>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    dManager.logMe(TAG,"file download complete");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    dManager.logMe(TAG,"file download error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(File file) {
                    dManager.logMe(TAG,"file download onNext: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            });
}
```

I call `downloadFile(String url, final File parentFolder` inside a number of for loops wherever I receive URL information.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can pass List<String> and use zip operator to combine the result.

Comment: Here I see, you download only one file at a time. If you have `List<Url>` then use the `Observable.from()` to iterate through each item and do the download so that you can clearly get to know the `onComplete()` of the `List<Url>` as well you can get the seprate `onComplete()` of each `url`. Instead of using `Observable.create()` use `fromCallable` because you're doing only one single operation there.

Comment: @AkbarShaEbrahim - I have implemented Single Operations as I need to handle onComplete for individual operations as well, I am guessing Observable.from() will give me status only when all of them have completed?

Comment: @DharmendraPratapSingh - I have checked few example of zip operators on internet. But I couldn't understand it clearly. How will I receive updates for both, Individual as well as once all the download is complete?

Comment: yup, you're correct. `Observable.from()` will give `onComplete` only if everything in the list emitted. inside the `flatMap` instead of having `Observable.create()` use `Observalbe.fromCallable()` which has it's own subscribe and `onComplete` to be get notified. Are you going to do any UI operation when the each url get's downloaded? or just gonna update some variables or DB?

Comment: Yes, I will update my code with Observable.fromCallable() within few minutes. Thanks for this valuable suggestion. Yep, I need to Update UI for few URLs, also need to maintain a progress to display it to the user..

Comment: In that case use `doOnNext()` to touch the UI to show individual progress bar for each url you're going to download. don't forget to call `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` just before the `doOnNext()` and switch back to background thread. If you're going to show only one progress bar then show it on the main `observable`

Comment: Okay, I will give it a try.. What do you mean by "main observable"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132287/discussion-between-akbar-sha-ebrahim-and-pooja-gaikwad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have a `List<String>` of urls:

```
    Observable.from(urls)
            .flatMap(url -> restApi.downloadFile(url))
            .concatMap(new Func1<Response<ResponseBody>, Observable<File>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<File> call(final Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                    try {
                        File file = new File(parentFolder.getAbsoluteFile(), uri.getLastPathSegment());
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }
                        BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file));
                        sink.writeAll(responseBodyResponse.body().source());
                        sink.close();
                        return Observable.just(file);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return Observable.error(e);
                    }
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<File>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    dManager.logMe(TAG, "file download complete");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    dManager.logMe(TAG, "file download error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(File file) {
                    dManager.logMe(TAG, "file download onNext: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you explain? How this works? Where do I receive all download completion status?

Comment: You will receive download completion status for each file in your onNext call, and download completion for all urls in onCompleted.

Comment: Okay, I will update you tomorrow.. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: Hey, sorry for late response but your answer worked perfectly.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an scratch example

```
Observable.from(List <Url>)
                .flatMap(Observable.fromCallable(downloadImageHereAndReturnTheFile())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        // Do on next is where you get notified when each url is getting downloaded
                        .doOnNext(doTheUIOperationHere())
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) //Switch to background thread if you want, in case if you do some other background task otherwise remove the above this and the following next operator 
                        .doOnNext(DoSomeOtherOperationHere()))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<R>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "The entire process of downloading all the image completed here");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(R r) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "You receive the file for each url");
                    }
                });
```